# android -- when i press button it crashes (when i don't enter data in the edittext fields )

Tags: android

I have an application where i have a screen with some edit text fields and when the user enters data ,then presses the button which does the calculation.
But if i don't enter data and just press the button,it crashes.

I thought  sth like when there is no data, then throw a message but i don't know how to do that!

Is there another way?

Here is this part.It calls the mass_calcs function which does the calculations.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.mass_calcs:
            mass_func();
            break;
        }
```

Here is the logcat :

```
01-08 18:45:25.650: I/jdwp(723): received file descriptor 13 from ADB
01-08 18:45:25.752: W/System.err(723): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
01-08 18:45:25.752: W/System.err(723): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
01-08 18:49:13.350: W/InputMethodManager(723): Ignoring onBind: cur seq=2, given seq=1
01-08 18:49:14.999: W/KeyCharacterMap(723): No keyboard for id 0
01-08 18:49:14.999: W/KeyCharacterMap(723): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-08 18:49:15.589: D/AndroidRuntime(723): Shutting down VM
01-08 18:49:15.589: W/dalvikvm(723): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
01-08 18:49:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:258)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:323)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation.number_mass.mass_func(number_mass.java:52)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation.number_mass.onClick(number_mass.java:45)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
01-08 18:49:15.692: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 18:49:15.799: I/dalvikvm(723): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-08 18:49:16.030: I/dalvikvm(723): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-08 18:49:19.361: I/Process(723): Sending signal. PID: 723 SIG: 9
01-08 19:15:31.900: D/AndroidRuntime(767): Shutting down VM
01-08 19:15:31.900: W/dalvikvm(767): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
01-08 19:15:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:258)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:323)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation.number_mass.mass_func(number_mass.java:51)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation.number_mass.onClick(number_mass.java:45)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
01-08 19:15:31.954: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 19:15:32.021: I/dalvikvm(767): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-08 19:15:32.259: I/dalvikvm(767): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-08 19:15:34.082: I/Process(767): Sending signal. PID: 767 SIG: 9
01-08 19:16:41.569: W/KeyCharacterMap(774): No keyboard for id 0
01-08 19:16:41.582: W/KeyCharacterMap(774): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-08 19:16:45.840: D/AndroidRuntime(774): Shutting down VM
01-08 19:16:45.840: W/dalvikvm(774): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
01-08 19:16:45.840: E/AndroidRuntime(774): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:258)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:323)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation.number_mass.mass_func(number_mass.java:51)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation.number_mass.onClick(number_mass.java:45)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
01-08 19:16:45.911: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 19:16:45.960: I/dalvikvm(774): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-08 19:16:46.141: I/dalvikvm(774): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-08 19:16:47.409: I/Process(774): Sending signal. PID: 774 SIG: 9
```

The mass_calcs class is :

```
public class mass_calcs extends Activity  {

    TextView masscalcs;


     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mass_calcs);

        masscalcs=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.masscalcs);       
        double res=getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("value");

        masscalcs.setText("Amount of mass remaining: "+res+" mg");
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post exception stack from logcat as well as related code. That way you will get accurate answer.

Comment: We don't know the exception, we can't see the method, not sure what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok on the getDouble() when there is no data you will find the app crashes as there is no double provided.

Where you have

```
case R.id.mass_calcs:
        mass_func();
        break;
    }
```

change it so that it has

```
case R.id.mass_calcs:

        if(isNumeric(masscalcs.getText().toString()))
        {
            mass_func();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please provide a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {     
      try  
      {  
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }
```

Comment: :If you mean mass_calcs and not masscalcs in "if(isNumeric(mass_calcs.getText().toString()))" ,then it gives me an error "The method getText is undefined for type View" . The masscalcs isn'n anything.What i must put there?Also, it gives me error at the "Toast.makeText(context..." context cannot be resolved to a variable" .I imported  android.widget.Toast.Anything else?Thank you!

Comment: You need to change context to a variable that can provide context. A bad example of what to swap could be "mass_calcs.this" (or whatever the class name is). Sorry there was a typo change mass_calcs to  masscalcs (which is your textview). If you still get errors let us know as I suspect you may need an extra statement in the IF.

Comment: Just realised my last comment may not have clear - mass_calcs.getText().toString() - "mass_calcs" is your class. You need to pass the view (the box) that the user will input the number in, which I thought was called "masscalcs" but I was wrong after looking again.

Answer (score 0):

you`re calling

`getDouble()`

, but when there is no correct Number, it crashes. Make sure it´s only called when a correct Number is entered.

Comment: And how can i do that?Write an if statement?In the mass_calcs class?And how?Thanks!

Comment: getExtras() returns a Bundle. Use the method containsKey("value") to determine if it contains your double.

Comment: I do "double res=getIntent().containsKey("value");" but its not correct.How to write it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your EditText string/editable?

1. if it's an editable, I don't think you can use
   `Double.parseDouble();` To change that when you're storing your editable in the intent, store the `editable.toString();` That should store a string.
2. If you're passing a string in already, and there's nothing inside the `parseDouble()` arguments, (if you're passing a null string), it also throws an exception. To avoid that, you should have an if-else in the area of storing your EditText string into your intent, that checks if the string is null or has something.

Comment: Or simply wrap it in a try ... catch.  You can't convert "" to a number, double or otherwise without causing an exception.

Comment: While this is an option is it not better to fail early rather than later? This would save processing and a few cycles etc. This is just an opinion though.

Comment: @TonyMaro yeah so what you could do is say: if(theString.length() == 0) //put whatever you want, like a toast
else intent.putExtra("value",Double.parseDouble(theString.trim()));
--

You could put it anywhere you want, as long as it's after pressing the button which grabs the editables from the edittext. If the application is a conversion calculator, then the processing saved time wouldn't really make a difference. But if you're looking for efficiency yeah you could put it earlier.